# display image as cursor

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

i am developing a portal, where client require animated cursor on page
I have done something but it is not working. steps which i have taken to make this is following:

1. in photoshop develop a image and save as cursor.ani
   2  pest this image in images folder.
2. pest the following code in html page  before body tag in head tag.

   ```
          <style type="text/css">
         <!--
             body {cursor:url("images/red_rose_turn_heart_shape_ty_clr.ani");
         }
           -->
          <style>
   ```

I am running this on following browser
1. FF 
2 IE6
3 netscape

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes instead of double quotes.